# Qual a melhor forma de elaborar IA para um jogo simples

Tags: javascript, jogos, inteligência-artificial

Baseado nesse joguinho, comecei a primeira geração completamente random, armazenando em uma matriz todos lados que a barra se moveu *(direita - 1, esquerda - 0)* e por fim *(na ultima posição do array)* quantos pontos conseguiu em cada partida.

***Minha ideia de como fazer***

Baseado nisso na segunda geração gostaria de descartar os jogos com menos pontos, e manter apenas um(ou mais, caso empate) jogo. E a partir dos movimentos desse jogo com maior pontuação começar a randomizar novamente para a segunda geração.

Os array são salvos dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria que o IA não soubesse o objetivo do jogo, apenas quero que ele apenas tenha base se está certo ou errado pela quantidade de pontos que se tem.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz de como posso fazer isso aprender as melhores jogadas ou também como executar da melhor forma a minha ideia ??

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está falando de algoritmos genéticos?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Sim, quero que o algoritmo aprenda sozinho qual forma ele quer jogar. Eu entendo mais ou menos como o algoritmos genéticos funcionam, eu apenas não sei muito bem qual a forma de encaixar isso no código.

Comment: @LucasCarezia aprendizado não supervisionado não necessita ser com algoritmo genético. Pode ser um agente voltado a utilidade. Tem redes neurais que aprendem sem ser supervisionado

Comment: Se quiser estudar mais sobre o assunto, conseguiram fazer uma IA que joga Mario. Creio que eles compartilham o como fizeram. Se não me engano, modelaram um agente voltado a utilidade

Comment: Exatamente, não quero que seja supervisionado. Porem a minha duvida é como fazer isso com o jogo e informações que tenho no momento, ou talvez quais informações mais eu preciso para conseguir fazer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todos os exemplos citados pelo @VictorStafusa em sua resposta são jogos complexos. Vamos analisar o *block breaker*, já que ele foi o exemplo da pergunta?

Para definir um agente inteligente, você deve determinar **PEAS**:

- **P**: performance
- **E**: ambiente (*environment*)
- **A**: atuadores
- **S**: sensores

Um modelo equivalente é o **PAGE**, mas ele tem limitações ontológicas que são melhores atendidas pelo **PEAS**:

- **P**: percepção
- **A**: ação
- **G**: objetivo (*goal*)
- **E**: ambiente (*environment*)

Notou que em ambos você precisa determinar o ambiente? Qual o ambiente do *block breaker*?

> Vou deixar o foco de múltiplos ambientes de lado já que só há atuação em um ambiente

Para começar a descrever o ambiente para o agente, precisamos descrever pelo menos as seguintes propriedades:

- dinamicidade
  o ambiente é dinâmico ou estático? Isto é, ele sofre alterações em seu estado interno independente do agente?
- determinismo
  o ambiente é determinístico ou estocástico? Existe alguma possibilidade de evento aleatório que altere seu estado interno? Obs: caos (conforme descrito na teoria do caos, o efeito borboleta) não é aleatório, apenas difícil de prever
- quantidade de agentes
  estamos lidando com quantos agentes inteligentes nesse meio?
- observabilidade
  o ambiente é completamente observável? Ou apenas se tem conhecimento parcial?
- continuidade temporal
  é um agente com ações episódicas? Ou uma ação tem consequência no estado interno do sistema que precisa ser levada em consideração em uma ação futura?

Respondendo:

- é um ambiente **dinâmico**, ele evolui continuamente no tempo; isso se devido à mecânica do jogo, já que é um jogo de ação, que exige intervenção em tempo real
- até onde me consta, é um ambiente **determinístico**: dada uma configuração, o próximo passo já está definido; mas pode ser **estocástico** se a física da colisão implantada permitir que duas colisões iguais resultem em resultados distintos (já vi isso no jogo Idle Balls da Voodoo para iPhone); ele também poderia ser estocástico se blocos surgissem no mapa sem intervenção do agente
- é um sistema tipicamente **mono-agente**, em que só se tem um único agente no ambiente
- ele é **completamente observável** pelo agente, não há informação escondida; talvez tenha informação que é apresentada porém desconhecida pelo agente (por exemplo, blocos cinzas exigem três colisões para quebrar, blocos dourados não quebram; bloco azul vale mais pontos do que o vermelho), mas isso não quer dizer que a informação não esteja lá
- não é episódico, uma ação interfere no estado interno do ambiente

Bem, começamos com essas características do ambiente. Ufa? Bem, ainda não...

O ambiente continua sendo regido por um conjunto de "leis". A essas "leis", quando estamos falando de jogos, damos o nome de "mecânicas". Essas mecânicas implicam como o universo evolui por si só (é um ambiente dinâmico, não é estático) e também como se pode interagir com o jogo.

Temos quatro mecânicas principais nesse jogo:

- movimento retilíneo uniforme
  dado que a bola segue seu trajeto
- colisões
  quando a bolinha entra em contato com algo (parede, bloco, raquete), há uma colisão que vai mudar o estado da bolinha e do colidido
- vazamento da bolinha 
  caso a bolinha passe pelo fundo, ela vazou
- movimentação da raquete
  o jogador pode definir como agir com a raquete

Em cima das mecânicas temos as regras. Por exemplo, vazamento da bolinha implica que perdeu uma vida (ou perdeu pontos). Blocos cinzas aguentam duas colisões e só partem na terceira. A raquete se move continuamente limitada a uma velocidade máxima, ou então ela faz saltos mágicos entre posições. A bolinha ao colidir com a raquete em movimento ganha/perde velocidade. Quebrar blocos gera pontos. Enfim, tem outras possíveis regras ainda que não vem ao caso.

Hmmm, percebeu que enquanto descrevíamos as regras do jogo tocamos em outro aspecto relativo ao ambiente? São os "elementos" do ambiente, os "objetos" contidos nele. Esses objetos são divididos nas seguintes classes:

- bolinha
- raquete
- bloco
- parede
- poço sem fim

Essas classes são importantes porque o agente vai **perceber** isso. A percepção do agente será relativo ao objeto e suas propriedades intrínsecas, que dependem de cada classe.

- bolinha
  esse objeto contém posição do centro (`(x,y)`), velocidade (direção/sentido/magnitude) e raio
- raquete
  esse objeto contém posição do centro (`(x,y)`) e, também, dimensões para calcular onde estão seus quatro vértices; pode conter também velocidade máxima, caso seja especificado que ele não salte posições
- bloco
  esse objeto contém posição do centro (`(x,y)`) e, também, dimensões para calcular onde estão seus quatro vértices, contém também cor, com possível implicação nas regras
- parede
  esse objeto está localizado nas bordas superior e laterais do ambiente, não tendo outras informações relevantes
- poço sem fim
  esse objeto está localizado na borda inferior do jogo, não tendo outras informações relevantes

E quais são as possíveis **atuações** do agente? Bem, apenas mexer a raquete. Mas isso pode se dar de duas maneiras:

- vai pro lado especificado na velocidade `X` (talvez `X` seja informável, talvez seja a velocidade máxima)
- vá para esta posição em específico (se tiver velocidade máxima, ele irá se deslocar em velocidade máxima, caso contrário será teletransporte)

E como faço o cálculo da **performance** do agente? Bem, podemos começar com o *score* do jogo.

Nesse caso em específico do *block breaker*, as ações não influenciam na performance diretamente, pois não importe o quanto você mova a raquete, isso só vai significar algo caso encontre a bolinha. Então o agente precisa calcular suas ações sabendo que a recompensa é não imediata. Isso é particularmente desafiador se o agente conhecer o mínimo da ontologia do ambiente, como você está requisitando. Uma função de aprendizado focado num modelo meio pavloviano de ação/recompensa ou ação/punição não funciona para este tipo de ambiente (ainda mais se a velocidade da bolinha for baixa).

Comment: Eu gostei muito da explicação, porem no final você disse oque não funcionaria, mas e oque funcionaria nesse caso ??

Comment: @LucasCarezia vou tentar elaborar mais, mas para esses tipos de jogos o melhor é não ter algo que aprenda, mas que simplesmente tenha alto desempenho, como o VictorStafusa pôs em sua resposta. E eu não tenho nada que, sem dica a priori, consiga elaborar melhor um aprendizado

Answer (score 5):

Se isso é um jogo similar a pong, block-breaker, arkanoid ou coisa assim, a inteligência artificial é muito mais simples que isso e algoritmos genéticos não vão te resolver isso.

Algoritmos genéticos servem para encontrar uma combinação de dados que apresente a melhor solução para um determinado problema fixo, e é algo computacionalmente caro de se obter. No seu caso, você tem um problema de agilidade, onde decisões tem que ser tomadas rapidamente em frações de segundos. Além disso, cada vez que você joga é diferente da vez anterior, pois a bolinha vai para um lado diferente, bate em um lugar diferente e a solução da tentativa anterior de nada servirá.

Resumindo, isso é um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132).

O algoritmo de inteligência artificial é simplesmente tentar seguir a bolinha da melhor forma possível. Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
function ia() {
    var raquete = ...;
    var bolinha = ...;
    var a = raquete.x + raquete.width / 2;
    var b = bolinha.x + bolinha.width / 2;
    if (a < b) {
        raquete.moverParaDireita();
    } else if (a > b) {
        raquete.moverParaEsquerda();
    }
    setTimeout(ia, 100);
}
```

Comment: Para ser considerado inteligente, precisa ter desempenho. Não envolve aprendizado, às vezes aprendizado ajuda a otimizar esse desempenho. Muito bem lembrado

Comment: Eu não sei se sua resposta me serve, eu editei a pergunta por que acabei esquecendo de colocar que eu quero que o IA não tenha conhecimento de seu objetivo, não quero que ele saiba que tem que seguir a bolinha, ele tem que descobrir isso sozinho baseado nos pontos que conseguiu fazer.

Comment: @Victor Stafusa Eu poderia classificar como inteligência artificial esse seu script? Uma inteligência que entendeu o conceito do jogo e evoluiu? Eu estou montando um script usando os conceitos de imaginação aumentada, para tentar prever aproximadamente onde a bolinha vai cair e posicionar a raquete. Não é dessa forma que tentamos jogar?

Comment: @GuilhermeIA Sim, esse script é uma inteligência artificial, embora seja uma bem simplória e incapaz de realizar qualquer tipo de aprendizado ou de imaginação. Trata-se de uma inteligência artificial por ter a finalidade de controlar um dos agentes do jogo e fazê-lo interagir com aquilo que é o seu ambiente, mesmo que o procedimento executado para fazer isso seja uma coisa extremamente mecânica e simplória.